# Solr + Jetty Gives HTTP 503 on Debian

Tags: solr, debian, jetty, http-status-code-503

(This is a cross-post from servefault. I'm posting it here because no one answered my post there, and I feel that this sort of hits an awkward space half-way between both stackoverflow and serverfault.)

I have modified the example project included with Solr for my needs (removing things like the example stopwords and defining my own schema). Running this project on my mac, everything works fine: I can start Jetty and run search queries. But when I push the project out to a Debian system, I get this error when I try to do search queries:

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE RequestURI=/solr
>
> Powered by jetty://

The request log shows that a request was made:

> 10.10.124.14 -  -  [22/06/2010:22:34:52 +0000] "GET /solr
>   HTTP/1.1" 503 1311

No error log is produced (at least not on in the ./logs directory).

I have tried to run this project both on openjdk and the Sun JRE. Both started jetty fine, but produced the same error when searching. I am running Debian 9.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the datastore in Debian is `/var/lib/solr/data` and you need to set that line in your version `solrconfig.xml` instead of the default which is in the base directory `/usr/share/solr/` which could be a read only file system.

Answer (score 0):

I've packaged the last solr version in Debian Testing. It seems, that there is some error in the solr configuration so that jetty starts, but it can't start the solr servlet. You must look in the jetty error log to find the reason.
There's lack of manpower in Java Packaging for Debian, so it may well be that there is an error in the solr-jetty package.
The solr-jetty package in Debian stable doesn't work as I recall. Please try from Debian testing!
If you indeed find an error, please don't use random forums but post a bug on bugs.debian.org!

Success!

Comment: I didn't build off of the solr-jetty Debian package. Instead I used example project bundled with the main Solr download, because I started development on a mac. And as far as I know, no error log is produced. Thanks!